# how to stop my VPN app from being running if a specific app is installed

Tags: java, android

I have an android VPN app running on OpenVPN core, so I want to check if a specific app is installed, on connecting the app, it will stop and request for such app to be uninstalled before it works.

I have seen such on an app using JSON for all the app id blacklisted and I really don't know to go about it on my own app.

here is the JSON image file:
[Blacklist.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f64NN.png)

[image]

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out what is the right package name of any installed application on your device.

**Getting Package Info:**

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packageName, PackageManager packageManager) {
    try {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can check in here like,

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
boolean isInstalled = isPackageInstalled("com.somepackage.name", pm);
if(isInstalled) {
 // NO VPN
}
else {
// start your service
}
```